# Get pixel coordinates through boundary coordinates

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, picturebox, pixel

I'm working on a project i need to find coordinates of pixels of selected area. I'm gaining this coordinates by simply clicking on a C# picture box. I need to find the pixel coordinates of the gray area as show in the picture in order to change the color of this ash area. is there a defined method in C# do do this? or please on how to archive this.

code samples will appreciated.

thanks in advance.

#### Selected Coordinates

[image: Selected coordinates]

#### Required Area

[image: required area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a point-in-polygon algorithm ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon )

```
static bool PointInPolygon(Point p, Point[] poly)
{
    Point p1, p2;
    bool inside = false;

    if (poly.Length < 3)
    {
        return inside;
    }

    Point oldPoint = new Point(poly[poly.Length - 1].X, poly[poly.Length - 1].Y);

    for (int i = 0; i < poly.Length; i++)
    {
        Point newPoint = new Point(poly[i].X, poly[i].Y);

        if (newPoint.X > oldPoint.X)
        {
            p1 = oldPoint;
            p2 = newPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            p1 = newPoint;
            p2 = oldPoint;
        }

        if ((newPoint.X < p.X) == (p.X <= oldPoint.X) 
            && ((long)p.Y - (long)p1.Y) * (long)(p2.X - p1.X) < ((long)p2.Y - (long)p1.Y) * (long)(p.X - p1.X))
        {
            inside = !inside;
        }

        oldPoint = newPoint;
    }

    return inside;
}
```

(from http://www.gamedev.net/topic/533455-point-in-polygon-c-implementation/ )

You may also use the .Net [HitTestCore Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms600289.aspx) if you use `System.Windows.Shapes.Polygon` to represent your polygon. I can't tell how easy that will work though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Click event, and pull out the mouse coordinates from the event. If the gray area is defined by a function, you can write a method to check if it's within the area specified. If not (it's just a static image), you should use the mouse coordinates to calculate which pixel you have clicked, and check its color value. There might be a method to get the color value where the mouse clicks (however, I might be confusing the method with the glReadPixel method in OpenGL).

Comment: I'm already acquiring the pixel cordless through picture box, but problem is in finding the pixel area of the shape.

Comment: Might this then be what you are looking for? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892462